# Is there a way to pass a variable with curly brace template tags through a method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` where I run an `ng-if` with a method that checks to see if certain parameters match between two sets of data. If there's a match, it updates `$scope` with the current match, which I can use to output my template:

```
<div ng-repeat="repeatedItem in repeatedItems">
    <a href="" ng-if="!matchData(repeatedItem.item1, repeatedItem.item2)">
        <img ng-src="{{ matchedItem.falseImageUrl }}" />
    </a>
    <a href="" ng-if="matchData(repeatedItem.item1, repeatedItem.item2)" ng-click="open(matchedItem.id)">
        <img ng-src="{{ matchedItem.imageUrl }}" />
        <time>{{ matchedItem.date }}</time>
        <div class="button-wrapper">
            <button class="btn">{{ matchedItem.text }}</button>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The thinking is that everything out of `repeatedItems` needed to show, unless an item in `repeatedItem` matched another data set, in which case you'd show the `matchedItem` instead.

Everything works fine, except for the `ng-click="open(matchedItem.id)` bit. Because `matchedItem.id` isn't wrapped in template tags, `ng-click` is always calling the latest iteration of matchedItem, so for all but the last repeated element, it's opening the wrong link.

The most obvious solution in my Angular-inexperienced mind would have been to do something like `ng-click="open( {{ matchedItem.id }} )`, but that throws an error. My next idea was something like `ng-click="open( {0} ):{{ matchedItem.id }}` - a `printf`-type of solution, but I haven't found any built-in Angular solution for that. I also thought about stashing `{{ matchedItem.id }}` in an attribute somewhere (`data-id="{{ matchedItem.id }}"`?), but I'm not sure how to call that attribute in the method.

It's possible (probable?) that I'm just not "thinking in Angular" yet, and I'm going about this the wrong way entirely. Or perhaps there's a directive that I'm just not aware of?

Here's the method:

```
$scope.matchData = function(item1, item2) {
    var isItAMatch = false;
    for (i=0; i<$scope.repeatedItems.length; i++) {
        itemAToMatch  = $scope.repeatedItems[i].itemA;
        itemBToMatch  = $scope.repeatedItems[i].itemB;

        if (itemAToMatch == item1 && itemBToMatch == item2) {
            isItAMatch = true;
            $scope.matchedItem = $scope.repeatedItems[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    return isItAMatch;
}
```

Comment: So each item (in repeatedItems) has its own matchedItem? and by the way you dont use interpolation when the variable can be evaluated against the scope inside an angular expression.

Comment: This looks... weird (no offense). I would consider 2 courses of action from here. A) Pre-condition your data so that it gets passed to the view in a way that you can show all items and not use `ng-if`. It looks like what you're doing can be expensive. B) Create a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) for your `ng-repeat` to filter and return items that you want to show.

Comment: @PSL I trimmed my code down; I have a different block that gets written if matchData returns false. The thinking was that everything out of repeatedItems needed to show, unless an item in repeatedItem matched another data set, in which case you'd show the other data instead. So, not all repeatedItems have a matchedItem.

Comment: @Mike no offense taken...I'm new to Angular and want to get better. If it's weird I want to know!

Comment: Edited the post to explain what I'm going for a bit better.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, or do you still need guidance here? You might want to edit your post to have an update with the current status...

Comment: @SamOnela - Oh man! It's been almost three years and I've moved on to Angular 2/4. Don't remember if I figured this out, nor do I still need guidance. Thanks for checking in.